# Installing the OpenCV prebuilt library on Ubuntu server 11.10

Tags: opencv, repository, ubuntu-11.04, ubuntu-server, launchpad

I am new to the Linux scene and I am trying to get OpenCV installed and running on our server as I need it to build and run a few applications on the system. I have followed the [Ubuntu package Install](http://opencv.willowgarage.com/wiki/Ubuntu_Packages) directions, but I seem to have an issue when I get to the install command. I get the terminal saying that it is reading the package list and after a few seconds I get a message saying that opencv cannot be found.

Has anyone had any experiences installing this library and can anyone possibly help guide me on how to use this whole setup? If it's any help I get a 404 error when I try to access the PPA in the update. Did I add the repository incorrectly?

Any advice is greatly appreciated.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

OpenCV 2.1 is quite old. Try setting up his new [PPA](https://launchpad.net/~gijzelaar/+archive/opencv2.3) for OpenCV 2.3.1. It has a Natty target.

Hope that's helpful!

Comment: This took me awhile to get working, but I got it all setup. Thanks